# Angular2 : Lodash working but triggers a Typescript error

Tags: typescript, angular, lodash

I did try to import lodash in my angular2 project. It's working fine, but I keep having in my log the following error :

```
TS2307 Cannot find module 'lodash'.
[error] import * as _ from "lodash"
```

However, I don't have any issue using it. Is there any tsconfig I have to change to prevent that from happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare external modules to TypeScript can type check them for you.

## Quick fix

`typings install lodash --global --save`

Comment: Do you know where does that stand in an Angular2 project ?

Comment: My bad this has the answer : http://mhartington.io/post/ionic2-external-libraries/ Thanks sir